# Converting inequalities to intervals

Tags: conversion, inequalities, intervals

I have an inequality, ie: 1.57116 < g < 14.1405

There will be a large set of similar inequalities, and I want to find the intersection of them all. I figured it would be easier to convert the inequalities to intervals first. Then find the intersection.

Is there an easy way to convert inequalities to intervals as the inequalities are generated? 
Alternatively, a way to find the intersection of a group of inequalities.

Comment: Try `Reduce[3 < x < 5 && 2 < x < 4]`

Comment: `Interval` represents closed intervals.  Do you wish to keep track of open and half-open intervals?

Answer (score 7):

I voted once to close this question as OP gave us not enough information about what is the desired output and the context.

Since I can't vote to close the second time I decided to write something :)

---

**Couple of thoughs at the begining.**

First of all, I'd use `Reduce` to deal with this problem and convert only the result. But if you ask I find it a good exercise to try doing what you ask for.

Pattern approach, as suggested by Anon, is no a bad idea. One just has to remember the issue I've pointed out in comments. Also, the origin of inequalities is important too.

Please take a look:

```
in = Reduce[3 < x < 5 && 2 < x < 4] (*progenitor of the inequality :)*)
in // FullForm
in // LogicalExpand // FullForm (*modyfied*)
3 < x < 4 // FullForm (*typed by hand*)
```

> ```
> Inequality[3,Less,x,Less,4]
> And[Less[3,x],Less[x,4]]
> Less[3,x,4]
> ```

All the same, all different. That's why I think using `LogicalExpand` for preventive purposes is a good idea. It will create, not the most compact solution, but matching the same pattern.

```
Reduce[3 < x < 5 && 2 < x < 4] (*automatic and modyfied*)    
3 < x < 4 // LogicalExpand // FullForm (*by hand & modyfied*)
```

> ```
> And[Less[3,x],Less[x,4]]
> And[Less[3,x],Less[x,4]]
> ```

But still we can see that there is some kind of inconsitence which will result in to much complicated patterns or to many of them. I mean that there is: `Less[3,x] And Less[x,4]` which could be also written `Greater[x, 3] And Less[x, 4]`. Good to know that we can convert all to consistent form with `Reduce`:

```
3 > x // FullForm
Reduce[3 > x] // FullForm
```

> ```
> Greater[3,x]
> Less[x,3]
> ```

---

**Ok, now we can create solution, step by step:**

```
(3 > x || x > 4 /. i_[s_?NumericQ, f_] :> Reduce[i[s, f]])
```

> ```
> x < 3 || x > 4
> ```

```
x < 3 || x > 4 /. {i_[s_, f_?NumericQ] :> Which[
                          MemberQ[{Greater, GreaterEqual}, i], Interval[{f, Infinity}],
                          MemberQ[{Less, LessEqual}, i], Interval[{-Infinity, f}]
                                               ]
                  }
```

> ```
> Interval[{-Infinity, 3}] || Interval[{4, Infinity}]
> ```

```
Interval[{-Infinity, 3}] || Interval[{4, Infinity}] /. {Or -> IntervalUnion, 
                                                        And -> IntervalIntersection}
```

> ```
> Interval[{-Infinity, 3}, {4, Infinity}]
> ```

---

**And all together**

```
conv[ineq_] := Fold[
                  ReplaceAll[#, #2] &,
                  ineq // LogicalExpand,
                  {
                   i_[s_?NumericQ, f_] :> Reduce[i[s, f]]
                   ,
                   {i_[s_, f_?NumericQ] :> Which[
                          MemberQ[{Greater, GreaterEqual}, i], Interval[{f, Infinity}],
                          MemberQ[{Less, LessEqual}, i], Interval[{-Infinity, f}]
                                                ]
                  }
                  ,
                  {Or -> IntervalUnion, And -> IntervalIntersection}
                 }
                 ]

conv[Reduce[3 < x < 5 && 2 < x < 4]]
```

> ```
> Interval[{3, 4}]
> ```

```
conv[3 < x < 5 && 2 < x < 4]
```

> ```
> Interval[{3, 4}]
> ```

**This solution assumes that intervals all always closed. Maybe I will generalize this if I will find some time in the future.**

Comment: This works well for just plain numbers, but doesn't work for `conv[ x >= Root[#^3 - 2 &, 1]]` which often shows up as result of reduce.

Comment: @Somnium thanks for feedback. Unfortunately this is not my area of expertise so I doubt I will find time to generalize this.

Comment: No problem, I have found solution myself and posted it as separate answer.

Answer (score 5):

Kuba's answer is great and has good explanation, but it is not working for intervals containing root objects.
Here is version using similar logic that works for those as well.

```
InequalitiesToIntervals[ineq_, x_] := LogicalExpand[ineq] /. {
  Greater[x, f_] -> Interval[{f, Infinity}],
  Greater[f_, x] -> Interval[{-Infinity, f}],
  GreaterEqual[x, f_] -> Interval[{f, Infinity}],
  GreaterEqual[f_, x] -> Interval[{-Infinity, f}],
  Less[x, f_] -> Interval[{-Infinity, f}],
  Less[f_, x] -> Interval[{f, Infinity}],
  LessEqual[x, f_] -> Interval[{-Infinity, f}],
  LessEqual[f_, x] -> Interval[{f, Infinity}],
  Or -> IntervalUnion,
  And -> IntervalIntersection
};
```

Example usage:

```
InequalitiesToIntervals[Reduce[x^7 - 5 x^3 - 1 > 0, x], x]
```

Output:

```
Interval[{Root[-1 - 5 #^3 + #^7& , 1, 0], Root[-1 - 5 #^3 + #^7& , 2, 0]}, {Root[-1 - 5 #^3 + #^7& , 3, 0], Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since version 10, there is [`RegionBounds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html) that can be used to do exactly this kind of job if the boolean expression is first converted to an `ImplicitRegion`:

```
boole = {
   1.57116 < x < 14.1405,
   0 < x < 1,
   0 < x < 10,
   0 <= x <= 1,
   x == 2,
   0 < x < 1 && -1 < x < 2,
   0 < x < 1 && 3 < x < 4,
   0 < x < 1 || 3 < x < 4,
   0 < x < Infinity,
   Element[x, Integers],
   x < 3 || x > 4
};

reg = ImplicitRegion[#, x] & /@ boole;

TableForm[
  {RegionBounds[#, "Minimal"], RegionBounds[#, "Sufficient"], 
     RegionBounds[#, "Finite"]} & /@ reg,
  TableHeadings -> {boole, {"Minimal", "Sufficient", "Finite"}}, 
  TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Default is `"Minimal"`, but for some cases, it might not return a proper interval. `"Finite"` returns a finite (not necessarily the smallest) bounding region for unbounded regions, e.g. halflines, halfplanes, etc. This is useful if one wants to provide a default interval for example to a `Slider` that is used to manipulate `x` that is by default not bound.

`RegionBounds` works in any dimensions:

```
boole = {
   0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1,
   0 <= x < 1 && -1 < y <= 2,
   0 <= x,
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1,
   x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && Gamma[x - y] <= x + y,
   x^2 + y^2 <= 4 || (x - 3)^2 + y^2 <= 3
   };

reg = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & /@ boole;

TableForm[{Quiet@RegionPlot[#, ImageSize -> 60, FrameTicks -> None, 
        PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], RegionBounds[#, "Minimal"], 
      RegionBounds[#, "Sufficient"], RegionBounds[#, "Finite"]} & /@ 
    reg /. {_RegionBounds | _RegionPlot -> "..."},
  TableHeadings -> {boole, {"RegionPlot", "Minimal", "Sufficient", 
     "Finite"}}, TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refinement of @István's answer that produces [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) objects:$\infty$

```
bounds[inequality_, x_] := First @ RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[inequality, x]]

ToInterval[inequality_, x_] := With[{rng = bounds[inequality, x]},
    System`Private`HoldSetValid[Interval[rng]]
]

t:ToInterval[_Or, _] := IntervalUnion @@ Thread[Unevaluated @ t, Or]
```

A couple examples showing the differences:

```
ToInterval[0<x<1 || 3<x<4, x]
ToInterval[x<3 || x>4, x]
```

> Interval[{0, 1}, {3, 4}]
>
> Interval[{-∞, 3}, {4, ∞}]

vs.

```
RegionBounds @ ImplicitRegion[0<x<1 || 3<x<4, x]
RegionBounds @ ImplicitRegion[x<3 || x>4, x]
```

> {{0, 4}}
>
> {{-∞, ∞}}

Another more complicated example:

```
ToInterval[
    Reduce[x^3 > 6 Sin[x] + 1, x],
    x
] //N
```

> Interval[{-1.7039, -0.168253}, {1.88567, ∞}]

Visualization:

```
Plot[{x^3, 6 Sin[x] + 1}, {x, -3, 4}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {None,Blue}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For each inequality:

```
Interval[Replace[1.57116 < g < 14.1405, Less[n__, __, m__] -> {n, m}]]
```

To find the intersection, as you have figured out, you can use `IntervalIntersection`.

Comment: Be careful with `a<x<b`, `Reduce`, `Piecewise` etc like to create different wrapper for them `Inequality[a, Less, x, Less, b]`. But `LogicalExpand` will make your inequalities match to `_[_,_]`.

Comment: If there are other types of inequalities than in the OP, this answer needs to be expanded for sure.

Comment: Of course but I'm talking about his one. Look here `Reduce[1 < x < 2] // FullForm`.

Comment: @Kuba Alright, that complicates things a lot. `LogicalExpand` may be a good approach as you suggest, but otherwise writing patterns that specifically conforms to the sort of inequality formatting the OP is dealing with should be straight forward if one knows what it is. So I guess the message to the OP is to use `FullForm` on his inequalities to figure that out.