# The UnitStep function and Intervals

Tags: functions, intervals

For the input

```
UnitStep[Interval[{-4, 5}]]
```

I get

```
Interval[{0, 1}]
```

Why is this not `Interval[{0,0}, {1,1}]`?

Comment: Because it is `Listable` (see `Attributes@UnitStep`) and can deal with real-valued intervals. This information can be easily found in documentation pages.

Comment: I understand that, but your comment is suggesting an answer to my question:  UnitStep is merely threading itself over the Interval, and doesn't "know" that it's an Interval that could result in a tighter interval result?  Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelE2 What do you mean by incorrect interval? `UnitStep[Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]]` yields `Interval[{0, 1}]`, similarly `Sin[Interval[{-Pi, Pi}]]` yields `Interval[{-1, 1}]`. What is your problem?

Comment: @Artes Isn't the range of `UnitStep` just the set {0, 1}?  I thought that's what `Interval[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]` represents.  Perhaps, I'm wrong, but that's how I understood it.  `Interval[{0,1}]` represents all reals between 0 and 1.  That's incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK I see your point, but since `Interval` is not `Listable` I don't understand why one expects anything yielding `Interval[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]`.

Comment: @Artes I don't think `Listable` has anything to do with the problem.  `Tan[Interval[{1, 2}]]` returns disjoint intervals `Interval[{-Infinity, Tan[2]}, {Tan[1], Infinity}]`.  If `UnitStep` worked correctly with `Interval`, `UnitStep[Interval[{a, b}]]` would return the range of values of `UnitStep` over that interval, either `Interval[{0,0}]`, `Interval[{1,1}]`, or `Interval[{0,0}, {1,1}]` depending on the signs of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Round`, `Floor` and `Ceiling` have the same problem. Sign works even worse: `Sign@Interval[{0, 1}]` returns `Interval[{-1, 1}]` not `Interval[{0, 0},{1, 1}]`.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a bug with `Interval`. What I find for this moment:

$$
\begin{array} {c|c|c|c}
\text{Function} & \text{Interval} & \text{Result} & \text{Should be}\\
\hline
\text{UnitStep} & [-4,5] & [0,1] & [0,0],[1,1]\\ 
\text{Sign} & [0,1] & [-1,1] & [0,0],[1,1]\\ 
\text{Round} & [0,2] & [0,2] & [0,0],[1,1],[2,2]\\ 
\text{Floor} & [0,2] & [0,2] & [0,0],[1,1],[2,2]\\ 
\text{Ceiling} & [0,2] & [0,2] & [0,0],[1,1],[2,2]\\
\end{array}
$$

Also almost all polynomials are working incorrectly

```
ChebyshevT[3, Interval[{-1, 1}]
```

> ```
> Interval[{-7, 7}]
> ```

It is well known that the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind $T_n(x)$ have values from $-1$ to $1$ if $-1\le x \le 1$.

```
 Plot[ChebyshevT[3, x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

The problem is that the polynomials are expanded first

```
ChebyshevT[3, x]
```

> ```
> -3 x + 4 x^3
> ```

And then `Interval[{-1, 1}]` is substituted

```
-3 Interval[{-1, 1}] + 4 Interval[{-1, 1}]^3
```

> ```
> Interval[{-7, 7}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange) to find the range of a function as a set of inequalities/equalities. For example:

```
FunctionRange[{UnitStep[x], -4 < x < 5}, x, y]
```

> y == 0 || y == 1

Here is a function to convert to [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) objects from inequalities from my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182807/45431) to [28790](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28790/45431):

```
bounds[inequality_, x_] := First @ RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[inequality, x]]

ToInterval[inequality_, x_] := With[{rng = bounds[inequality, x]},
    System`Private`HoldSetValid[Interval[rng]]
]

t:ToInterval[_Or, _] := IntervalUnion @@ Thread[Unevaluated @ t, Or]
```

and the reverse:

```
FromInterval[Interval[a___],x_]:=Less[#1,x,#2]& @@@ Unevaluated[Or[a]]
```

With these functions we can define an function `IntervalRange` to find the range of a function as an [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval) object:

```
IntervalRange::nmet = "Unable to find the range with the available methods.";

IntervalRange[f_, i_Interval] := With[
    {reg = Catch[iRange[f, FromInterval[i, x], x], "FRFailure"]},
    reg /; reg =!= $Failed
]

iRange[f_, reg_, x_] := Module[{prec = Precision[reg], rng},
    rng = Quiet[
        Check[
            FunctionRange[{f[x], SetPrecision[reg, prec+10]}, x, y],

            Message[RangeInterval::nmet];
            Throw[$Failed, "FRFailure"],

            FunctionRange::nmet
        ],
        FunctionRange::nmet
    ];
    ToInterval[N[rng, prec], y]
]

iRange[f_, reg_Or, x_] := IntervalUnion @@ (iRange[f, #, x]& /@ reg)
```

Your example:

```
IntervalRange[UnitStep, Interval[{-4, 5}]]
```

> Interval[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]

Some other examples:

```
IntervalRange[Function[x, ChebyshevT[3, x]], Interval[{-1, 1}]]
```

> Interval[{-1, 1}]

and:

```
IntervalRange[Function[x, x + x^2], Interval[{-∞, ∞}]]
```

> Interval[{-(1/4), ∞}]