# Interval arithmetic for DawsonF (or other special functions)

Tags: special-functions, intervals

I am currently trying to estimate a complicated expression involving `DawsonF` using interval arithmetic.  The interval arithmetic is partially supported by Mathematica (most of the elementary functions are defined for `Interval[{...}]` arguments) but the `DawsonF` function doesn't seem to be a part of that implementation (along with other special functions such as `Hypergeometric1F1`, which could be used instead of the `DawsonF`).

1. Is there any way to evaluate `DawsonF` on intervals using some built in Mathematica functions?
2. If not, are there any algorithms for computing `DawsonF` on intervals, which can be implemented in Mathematica?  If so, can you please post a reference?  The only paper on that topic, that I am aware of, is [1] but it looks dated (1992) and the algorithm presented there seems complicated (there is a lot of special cases).

I am interested in evaluating `DawsonF` on all subintervals of the real axis.

[1] http://interval.louisiana.edu/reliable-computing-journal/1992/interval-computations-1992-3-pp-17-26.pdf

Comment: The `FunctionRange` only works for the whole real line (or the complex plane) and even then `FunctionRange[DawsonF[x], x, y, Reals]` returns an inexact result `-0.541044 <= y <= 0.541044`.

Answer (score 1):

```
intDawson[i_Interval] := Module[{peak, xpeak},
  {peak, xpeak} = {NMaxValue[DawsonF[x], x], NArgMax[DawsonF[x], x]};
  Interval[
   If[IntervalMemberQ[i, xpeak], {#[[1]], peak}, #] &@
      If[IntervalMemberQ[i, -xpeak], {-peak, #[[2]]}, #] &@
    Sort[DawsonF @@ i // N]]
  ]


intDawson[Interval[{-10, 10}]]
(* Interval[{-0.541044, 0.541044}] *)

intDawson[Interval[{0, 10}]]
(* Interval[{-2.22507*10^-308, 0.541044}] *)
```

Comment: In a sense this works but I need a guarantee that $x\in I$ implies $f(x)\in f(I)$.  For that one has to prove rigorous error bounds for each step that involves a form of numerical approximation (like `NMaxValue` or `Dawson[N[...]]`).  If you take a look at the paper I referenced the author does exactly that.  Now that I think about it I am not even sure if the rigorous relation above holds for the interval arithmetic already implemented in Mathematica.  It seems to hold but the code is closed source and they don't reference any papers or algorithms about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of my [`IntervalRange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182809/45431) function for this purpose, reproduced below:

```
(* message *)
IntervalRange::nmet = "Unable to find the range with the available methods.";

(* main function *)
IntervalRange[f_, i_Interval] := With[
    {reg = Catch[iRange[f, FromInterval[i, x], x], "FRFailure"]},
    reg /; reg =!= $Failed
]

(* find range using FunctionRange *)
iRange[f_, reg_, x_] := Module[{prec = Precision[reg], rng},
    rng = Quiet[
        Check[
            FunctionRange[{f[x], SetPrecision[reg, prec+10]}, x, y],

            Message[RangeInterval::nmet];
            Throw[$Failed, "FRFailure"],

            FunctionRange::nmet
        ],
        FunctionRange::nmet
    ];
    ToInterval[N[rng, prec], y]
]
iRange[f_, reg_Or, x_] := IntervalUnion @@ (iRange[f, #, x]& /@ reg)

(* ToInterval helper function *)
bounds[inequality_, x_] := First @ RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[inequality, x]]
ToInterval[inequality_, x_] := With[{rng = bounds[inequality, x]},
    System`Private`HoldSetValid[Interval[rng]]
]
t:ToInterval[_Or, _] := IntervalUnion @@ Thread[Unevaluated @ t, Or]

(* FromInterval helper function *)
FromInterval[Interval[a___],x_]:=Less[#1,x,#2]& @@@ Unevaluated[Or[a]]
```

Dr.belarisarius' examples:

```
IntervalRange[DawsonF, Interval[{-10, 10}]]
% //N
```

> Interval[{DawsonF[
>      Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, -0.924138873004591767012823271504}]], 
>     DawsonF[Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, 
>        0.924138873004591767012823271504}]]}]
>
> Interval[{-0.541044, 0.541044}]

```
IntervalRange[DawsonF, Interval[{0, 10}]]
% //N
```

> Interval[{0, 
>     DawsonF[Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, 
>        0.924138873004591767012823271504}]]}]
>
> Interval[{-2.22507*10^-308, 0.541044}]

If one is willing to mess with built-in symbols, it is possible to add support for Interval objects to DawsonF:

```
Unprotect[DawsonF];
DawsonF[i_Interval] /; !TrueQ@$Interval := Block[{$Interval = True},
    IntervalRange[DawsonF, i]
]
Protect[DawsonF];
```

Then:

```
DawsonF[Interval[{-10,10}]]
DawsonF[Interval[{0, 10}]]
DawsonF[Interval[{-2, -1}, {1, 2}]]
```

> Interval[{DawsonF[
>      Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, -0.924138873004591767012823271504}]], 
>     DawsonF[Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, 
>        0.924138873004591767012823271504}]]}]
>
> Interval[{0, 
>     DawsonF[Root[{-(1/2) + DawsonF[#1] #1 &, 
>        0.924138873004591767012823271504}]]}]
>
> Interval[{-DawsonF[1], -DawsonF[2]}, {DawsonF[2], DawsonF[1]}]