# What is the difference in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, inequalities

Here is some pattern code:

```
parse2[a_ < b_ < c_] := (Print["Matched!"];)
iterAnd[x_ && y_] := y;

Print["Good example"]
ccr = a < b < c
parse2[ccr]

Print["Bad example"]
ccr2 = iterAnd[BooleanConvert[Reduce[a < b < c, {b}, Reals]]]
parse2[ccr2]
```

And here is the result:

```
Good example
a < b < c
Matched!

Bad example
a < b < c
parse2[a < b < c]
```

The source expressions look similar, but pattern match results vary. What is the reason?

Comment: I find your question hard to follow.  Can you create a *simple* but *complete* example that shows the problem?  Show the input, actual output and expected output.  Your example is neither simple nor complete at the moment.

Comment: closely related: [Converting inequalities to intervals](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32473/5478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is confusing indeed.  Let me repeat what you are showing here:

```
In[25]:= ccr2    
Out[25]= a < b < c

In[26]:= parse2[ccr2]    
Out[26]= parse2[a < b < c]

In[27]:= parse2[a < b < c]

During evaluation of In[27]:= Matched!
```

`Out[26]` and `In[27]` *looks* exactly the same, yet one evaluates the other doesn't.  Are they really the same?  The first thing to check in such cases is their [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html).

```
In[30]:= FullForm[ccr2]
Out[30]//FullForm= Inequality[a,Less,b,Less,c]

In[31]:= FullForm[a<b<c]
Out[31]//FullForm= Less[a,b,c]
```

As you can see, they are not the same, even though they are formatted in the same way in `StandardForm`.  This explains why there is a match in one case but there isn't a match in another.

I'll update the post if I can come up with a workaround that seems better than the obvious (i.e. manual transformation of `Inequality` expressions).

---

Possible workarounds:

The undocumented function `` Reduce`InequalityExpand `` seems to convert inequalities such as `a < b < c` to the form `a < b && b < c`.  This may be useful for your purposes.

The documented function [`LogicalExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand.html) also carries out this transformation.  But it also does other things which may or may not be desirable depending on your specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for this function, let it be the weapon of a last chance. :) For my purpose it would be better not to expand this. The final goal is to extract integration limits from the system of inequalities. So I take a big expression, reduce it to an disjunctive form, which  carries this way all limits cyphered in inequalities. So  I want just to parse this result.

Comment: @ИгорьМоисеев You could also try matching both on `Less[a_, b_, c_]` and `Inequality[a_, Less, b_, Less, c_]`.  But then we'd have to think very carefully if there are any other possible forms that represent the same thing ...

Comment: Thank you very much, thought about this too. :)