# Extract result of Reduce when solving an inequalities

Tags: equation-solving

I defined this function

```
getInt[ptmin_, ptmax_, sqrts_] :=
(
Reduce[4 ptmin^2/sqrts^2 < 1 - x^2 < 4 ptmax^2/sqrts^2]
);
```

which solves an inequality. It returns for example

```
In: getInt[50, 250, 1000] // N

Out: -0.994987 < x < -0.866025 || 0.866025 < x < 0.994987
```

I need to integrate a function over these intervals so I want to use these results on an integral. How to extract these values from the output of Reduce?

For example, I want to store these values on 4 variables

```
xmin1 = -0.994987
xmax1 = -0.866025 
xmin2 = 0.866025
xmax2 = 0.994987
```

Comment: Closely related: [Converting inequalities to intervals](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28790/12)

Answer (score 5):

Regions can help.

```
int = getInt[50, 250, 1000] // N
(* -0.994987 < x < -0.866025 || 0.866025 < x < 0.994987 *)

Integrate[x^2, x ∈ ImplicitRegion[int, x]]
(* {0.223679} *)
```

Why the braces around the result?  When using the syntax `x \[Element] region`, `x` is considered to be a vector.  This is a 1D region, so it is a 1D (single-component) vector.

Verification of the result:

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, -0.9949874371066199`, -0.8660254037844386`}] + 
 Integrate[x^2, {x, 0.8660254037844386`, 0.9949874371066199`}]
(* 0.223679 *)
```

---

Alternative for versions prior to 10.0, when the region functionality was introduced:

```
Integrate[x^2 Boole[int], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

`Integrate` and `NIntegrate` are smart about `Boole` are able to resolve the integration boundaries internally.

Answer (score 3):

To extract the boundaries:

```
int = getInt[50, 250, 1000] // N
```

> -0.994987 < x < -0.866025 || 0.866025 < x < 0.994987

```
reg = RegionBounds @ ImplicitRegion[#, x] & /@ (List @@ BooleanConvert @ int)
```

> {{{-0.994987, -0.866025}}, {{0.866025, 0.994987}}}

```
x = Flatten @ reg
```

> {-0.994987, -0.866025, 0.866025, 0.994987}

Comment: Do you think `BooleanConvert` would make this safer?  It's not clear to me if it can happen that the result from Reduce is not already in disjunctive normal form when there were no parameters.

Comment: @Szabolcs Not sure, but I guess it won't do any harm to add `BooleanConvert` just in case.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question:

```
getInt[ptmin_, ptmax_, sqrts_] := (Reduce[
    4 ptmin^2/sqrts^2 < 1 - x^2 < 4 ptmax^2/sqrts^2]);
sol = getInt[50, 250, 1000] // N

(*-0.994987 < x < -0.866025 || 0.866025 < x < 0.994987*)

{xmin1, xmax1} = {sol[[1, 1]], sol[[1, 5]]}
{-0.994987, -0.866025}

{xmin2, xmax2} = {sol[[2, 1]], sol[[2, 5]]}
{0.866025, 0.994987}
```