# How can I test if two inequalities have a common part?

Tags: functions, regions, algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

I want to check whether $1 \leq x\leq2$ and $1.5\leq x\leq2.5$ have common part, what function can do this?

Answer (score 9):

Does a value of `x` which fulfils both conditions exist?

```
Resolve[Exists[x, 1 <= x <= 2 && 1.5 <= x <= 2.5]]

(* True *)
```

Also the same; you can replace `&&` with just a list of conditions:

```
Resolve[Exists[x, {1 <= x <= 2, 1.5 <= x <= 2.5}]]
```

`Reduce` also works in this case.

Note that although in this case one can expect a Boolean answer, it doesn't need to be always so:

```
Resolve[Exists[x, {1 <= x <= a, 3/2 <= x <= 5/2}], Reals]

(* 3/2 - a <= 0 *)
```

Comment: (+1) and a minor comment: replacing `Reduce` with `Resolve` also does the trick :-)

Comment: @bmf Yeah, maybe a better option.

Comment: I would not say a better option to be honest, mainly because I also used `Reduce`, but let's call it a pedagogical exposition for the interested readers :-)

Comment: @bmf `Resolve` is specifically meant for eliminating `Exists` quantifier, though.

Comment: I know, I am just not happy that it was not my go-to answer (blushing)

Answer (score 7):

```
cond1 = 1 <= x <= 2;
cond2 = 1.5 <= x <= 2.5;

ℛ = 
 RegionIntersection @@ (ImplicitRegion[#, {x}] & /@ {cond1, cond2})

res = Reduce[Element[{x}, ℛ], x]

NumberLinePlot[{cond1, cond2, res}, x]
```

[image]

The filled circles on the plot indicate that the point is also included. As an experiment, learners can try the following to see the difference in the result.

```
cond2 = 1.5 < x <= 2.5;
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for [**`Reduce`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html?v=13.2)

```
one = 1 <= x <= 2;
two = Rationalize[1.5 <= x <= 2.5, 0];
Reduce[one && two]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 6):

If you're not picky about open/closed interval boundaries, then [`Interval`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) can do this:

```
IntervalIntersection[Interval[{1, 2}], Interval[{3/2, 5/2}]]
(*    Interval[{3/2, 2}]    *)
```

[Tutorial on interval arithmetic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/IntervalArithmetic.html)

Comment: This was the second option I was thinking about, but took the literal track of expecting that the user has inequalities, not `Interval`s at hand. Also I wanted to demonstrate `Exists`, which isn't necessarily obvious to users coming from other languages.

Comment: Also, it's a possibly unintuitive that no overlap is indicated in this case by `Interval[]`, and empty interval that is.

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to Roman solution, but uses Carl Woll answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28790/converting-inequalities-to-intervals) to automatically convert inqualities to intervals. (might be useful for non-interactive coding)

```
bounds[inequality_, x_] := First@RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[inequality, x]]

ToInterval[inequality_, x_] := 
 With[{rng = bounds[inequality, x]}, 
  System`Private`HoldSetValid[Interval[rng]]]

t : ToInterval[_Or, _] := IntervalUnion @@ Thread[Unevaluated@t, Or]
```

Using Carl's code above, now you can do as similar to Roman answer

```
v1 = ToInterval[1 <= x <= 2, x]
v2 = ToInterval[1.5 <= x <= 2.5, x]
IntervalIntersection[v1, v2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[help on Interval](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html)